# Allow only authenticated users on the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to know how I can configure a page to only allow authenticated users in Firebase. I'm having difficulty setting up my site, I would expect the user to enter the login and password and, after authenticating, would be directed to his profile.

The profile (web page), to which the user was directed, has the URL

> www.example.com/"user.uid"/index.html

but this page can only be accessed for users who are authenticated, so if someone accesses the URL

> www.example.com/"user.uid"/index.html

the user must Be directed to the main page

> http://www.example.com

The code on login page:

```
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e =>{
        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass);
        promise
        .then(user => window.location.href="http://www.example.com/" + user.uid + "/index.html")
        .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    })
```

The code on client page:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if(firebaseUser){
            console.log(firebaseUser);
        }else{
            window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
            console.log("offline");
                    }
});
```

The problem I've encountered is that when you redirect to the client page, the user's status goes offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is optimized to work client side and specifically single page applications. You can do one of the following:

1. Handle authentication check client side: Add an onAuthStateChanged listener on that page www.example.com/"user.uid"/index.html: If the user is not logged in and doesn't match the uid of that page, redirect to the sign in page.
2. Use cookies. After sign in, you can send the Firebase ID token to the backend and mint a session cookie or just use the ID token as the session cookie. Make sure you validate that ID token before you do so. Firebase has a node.js and java libraries to help with that. You have to also make sure you constantly listen to auth changes on the client side as the Firebase ID token expires every hour. Anyway, using cookies, the next time the user requests a restricted resource, you check the cookie is valid and matches the expected user before you serve that resouce, otherwise 302 to a sign in page.